# ¿Cuáles son las nuevas características de C++17?

Tags: c++, c++1z, c++-faq, estándares

> **Traducción basada en la pregunta de [Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38060436/499359) del SO en Inglés**.

---

Ya se han aprobado todas las características de C++17, así que es poco probable que sufra cambios importantes. Se hicieron centenares de propuestas para C++17.

¿Cuáles de estas características se añadieron a C++ en C++17?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38060436/499359

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Características del lenguaje:

### Plantillas y Código Genérico

#### Deducción del argumento de plantilla para clases plantilla.

Documento técnico [`p0091r2`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r2.html).

Supongamos que tenemos las siguientes definiciones:

```
std::vector<int> vi1 = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 };
std::vector<int> vi2;
std::mutex m;
unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m, std::defer_lock);

template<class Func> class Foo() { 
public: 
    Foo(Func f) : func(f) {} 
    void operator()(int i) { 
        os << "Calling with " << i << std::endl;
        f(i); 
    } 
private: 
    Func func; 
    std::mutex mtx;
};
```

Antes del estándar C++17, los siguientes objetos se deben construir tal y como se muestra:

```
pair<int, double> p(2, 4.5);
auto t = make_tuple(4, 3, 2.5);
copy_n(vi1, 3, back_inserter(vi2));

// Virtualmente imposible pasar una lambda al constructor
// de una clase plantilla sin declarar la lambda
for_each(vi2.begin(), vi2.end(), Foo<???>([&](int i) { ...}));

lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(foo.mtx);
// Notacion del documento tecnico N4470
lock_guard<std::mutex, std::unique_lock<std::mutex>> lck2(foo.mtx, ul);

auto hasher = [](X const & x) -> size_t { /* ... */ };
unordered_map<X, int, decltype(hasher)> ximap(10, hasher);
```

Si permitimos que el compilador deduzca los argumentos para los constructores de clases plantilla, podemos replazar el código anterior con:

```
pair p(2, 4.5);
tuple t(4, 3, 2.5);
copy_n(vi1, 3, back_insert_iterator(vi2));

// Ahora esto es facil, en lugar de virtualmente impossible
for_each(vi.begin(), vi.end(), Foo([&](int i) { ...}));

auto lck = lock_guard(foo.mtx);
lock_guard lck2(foo.mtx, ul);

// NOTA: la deducción de argumentos de plantilla deduce
// los argumentos no explícitos
unordered_map<X, int> ximap(10, [](X const & x) -> size_t { /* ... */ });
```

#### Declarar argumentos de plantilla no-tipo con `auto`.

Documento técnico [`p0127r1`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r1.html).

El tipo de un parámetro de plantilla no-tipo debe ser especificado explícitamente, esto provoca una verbosidad innecesaria y reduce la flexibilidad de aquellas plantillas que se pretende que reciban argumentos constantes de cualquier tipo:

```
template <typename T, T v> struct S { }; // Definicion
S<decltype(x), x> s;                     // Instanciacion
```

El ejemplo usa `decltype` para obtener el tipo de `x` (una constante en tiempo de compilación) antes de pasar ambos parámetros a `S`. Lo ideal sería modificar la declaración de `S` de manera que el tipo de `x` no fuera requerido:

```
S<x> s; // Instanciacion deseada
```

Esto se consigue permitiendo el uso de `auto` en la lista de parámetros de plantilla:

```
template <auto v> struct S; // Deduce el tipo de v
```

#### Permitir la evaluación constante de todos los argumentos de plantilla no-tipo.

Documento técnico [`n4198`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4198.html).

Antes de C++17, C++ permite los siguientes parámetros de plantilla no-tipo:

- Cualquier Tipo Integral o Enumerado que sea una expresión constante.
- Punteros que apunten a objetos en memoria estática, funciones con enlazado o expresiones constantes que se evaluen como puntero nulo.
- Referencias a objetos en memoria estática o funciones con enlazado.
- Punteros a miembros `&X::y` o expresiones constantes que se evaluen como puntero-a-miembro nulo.

A partir de C++17 los parámetros de plantilla no tipo pueden ser:

- Cualquier Tipo Integral o Enumerado que sea una expresión constante.
- Punteros que apunten a un objeto completo en memoria estática, una función o un puntero nulo.
- Referencias a un glvalue referenciando a un objeto completo en memoria estática o una función.
- Cualquier expresión constante de puntero a miembro.
- `std::nullptr_t`.

#### Permitir `typename` en parámetros-plantilla (template template)

Documento técnico [`n4051`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4051.html)

Es obligatorio usar `class` para el tipo de un parámetro-plantilla:

```
template<template<typename> class X> struct S; // class es requerido
```

A partir de C++17 también se podrá:

```
template<template<typename> typename X> struct S; // Se puede usar class o typename
```

#### Expresiones plegables<sup>1</sup>.

Documento técnico [`n4295`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4295.html).

Una expresión plegable, pliega un paquete de parámetros de plantilla sobre un operador binario plegable.

Los operadores plegables son:

> ```
> +  -  *  /  %  ^  &  |  ~  =  <  >  <<  >>
> +=  -=  *=  /=  %=  ^=  &=  |=  <<=  >>=
> ==  !=  <=  >=  &&  ||  ,  .*  ->*
> ```

- Una expresión del tipo `(... operador expresión)` en que `op` es un operador plegable se conoce como pliegue unario a la izquierda.
- Una expresión del tipo `(expresión operador ...)` en que `op` es un operador plegable se conoce como pliegue unario a la derecha.

Los pliegues unarios a izquierda y derecha se conocen como pliegues unarios. En un pliegue unario, la expresión debe contener un paquete de parámetros sin expandir.

- Una expresión del tipo `(expresión1 operador1 ... operador2 expresión2)` en que `operador1` y `operador2` son operadores plegables se conoce como pliegue binario.

En un pliegue binario, `operador1` y `operador2` deben ser el mismo operador plegable y `expresión1` o `expresión2` deben contener un paquete de parámetros sin expandir mas no ambas. Si `expresión2` contiene un paquete de parámetros sin expandir, la expresión se conoce como pliegue binario a izquierda. Si `expresión1` contiene un paquete de parámetros sin expandir, la expresión se conoce como pliegue binario a derecha.

La instanciación de una expresión plegable produce:

- `((Expr1 operador Expr2) operador ...) operador ExprN` para pliegues unarios a la izquierda.
- `Expr1 operador (... operador (ExprN-1 operador ExprN))` para pliegues unarios a la derecha.
- `(((Expr operador Expr1) operador Expr2) operador ...) operador ExprN` para pliegues binarios a la izquierda.
- `Expr1 operador (... operador (ExprN-1 operador (ExprN operador Expr)))` para pliegues binarios a la derecha.

En cada caso:

- `operador` es el operador plegable
- `N` es el número de elementos en la expansión del paquete de parámetros.
- `ExprX` es generado al instanciar el patrón y reemplazar cada parámetro del paquete con el X-ésimo elemento.

Para una expresión plegable binaria, `Expr` es generado al instanciar la expresión que no contiene un paquete de parámetros sin expandir:

```
template<typename... Args>
bool todos(Args... args) { return (args && ...); }

bool b = todos(true, true, true, false);
```

Al instanciar la plantilla `todos` obtendríamos:

```
bool todos(bool e1, bool e2, bool e3, bool e4) { return ((e1 && e2) && e3) && e4; }
```

#### Nuevas normas de deducción para `auto` con listas entre llaves.

Documento técnico [`n3922`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html)

En C++17 cambian las normas de deducción de tipos (`auto`) para las deducciones en que intervienen listas de elementos.

Para la inicialización por copia de lista:

- La deducción de tipo de `auto` deduce `std::initializer_list` si los tipos en la lista son idénticos o en caso contrario será un error de compilación.

Para la inicialización por lista:

- En listas con un sólo elemento, `auto` deducirá el tipo de ese elemento; previamente a C++17 deducía una `std::initializer_list` de un elemento.
- En listas con más de un elemento, `auto` no deducirá, será un error de compilación.

Ejemplo:

```
auto a = { 1, 2 };   // deduce std::initializer_list<int> de dos elementos
auto b = { 3 };      // deduce std::initializer_list<int> de un elemento
auto c{ 3 };         // deduce int, antes deducia std::initializer_list<int> de un elemento
```

#### `if` constante.

Documento técnico [`p0128r1`](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0128r1.html).

Un `if` cuya condición se evalúa en tiempo de compilación y la rama no tomada se descarta de la compilación, es útil para simplificar ciertos códigos:

```
void funcion()
{
    // Se requiere la funcion vacia para eliminar la recursion
}

template <class T> 
void funcion(T&& elemento)
{
    // Hacer cosas con el elemento
}

template <class T, class... Parametros>
void funcion(T&& cabeza, Parametros&&... cola)
{
    funcion(cabeza);
    funcion(cola...); // Finaliza la recursion cuando cola... es una lista vacia
}
```

Con `if` constante, la funcion vacia no es necesaria:

```
template <class T> 
void funcion(T&& elemento)
{
    // Hacer cosas con el elemento
}

template <class T, class... Parametros>
void funcion(T&& cabeza, Parametros&&... cola)
{
    funcion(cabeza);
    constexpr if (sizeof...(cola))
    {
        // No se genera esta parte del codigo si cola... es una lista vacia
        funcion(cola...);
    }
}
```

### Lambdas

#### Lambdas expresión constante

Documento técnico [`n4487`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4487.pdf).

Antes de C++17 estaba prohibido que una lambda o su instancia (closure) formara parte de una expresión constante; esta restricción era inconsistente (ya que los funtores tradicionales no disponen de ella) e innecesaria:

```
// Este codigo es valido en C++17 pero incorrecto en estandares previos
constexpr auto L = [](int i) { return i; }; // Correcto en C++17

auto L2 = [] { return 0; };
constexpr int I = L2(); // Correcto en C++17
```

#### Capturar `*this` en lambdas

Documento técnico [`p0018r3`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0018r3.html).

Las lambdas declaradas en una función miembro no estática, capturan `this` implícita o explícitamente para acceder a las variables del objeto a través del puntero `this`; por este motivo la captura del contexto del objeto por copia o por referencia son iguales:

```
struct S {
    int x ;

    void f() {
        // Ambas lambdas son identicas pese a que su captura sea diferente:
        auto a = [&]() { x = 42 ; } // El acceso a x se transforma en (*this).x = 42
        auto b = [=]() { x = 43 ; } // El acceso a x se transforma en (*this).x = 43
    }
};
```

Esto provoca problemas en programación asíncrona pues puede provocar el uso de punteros a memoria que ha dejado de ser válida:

```
class Tarea {
private:
    int valor ;
public:
    Tarea() : valor(42) {}
    std::future generar()
    { return std::async( [=]()->int{ return valor ; }); }
};

std::future foo()
{
    Tarea tmp ;
    // La closure asociada con el std::future devuelto
    // tiene un puntero this implicito.
    return tmp.generar();
    // El puntero this de la closure deja de ser valido
    // al finalizar la funcion, despues del return
}

int main()
{
    std::future f = foo();
    f.wait();
    // El valor del futuro no es valido porque
    // el objeto que lo genero ya ha sido destruido
    assert( 42 == f.get() );
    return 0 ;
}
```

Pudiendo capturar `*this` soluciona el problema.

### Atributos

Los [Atributos](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) fueron añadidos en C++11 y C++17 añade nuevos atributos.

#### Atributos `[[fallthrough]]`, `[[nodiscard]]` y `[[unused]]`

Documento técnico [`p0068r0`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0068r0.pdf).

El atributo `[[fallthrough]]` se usa como una instrucción, la instrucción `[[fallthrough]]` se pone justo antes de una etiqueta `case` en un `switch` y su objetivo es marcar que la ejecución *caerá hasta* la próxima etiqueta `case` de manera intencionada:

```
switch (c) {
    case 'a':
        f(); // WARNING: falta break
    case 'b':
        g();
        [[fallthrough]]; // Correcto
    case 'c':
        h();
}
```

El atributo `[[nodiscard]]` puede usarse sobre tipos o sobre funciones; si ha sido marcado así y el tipo o el retorno de función no es usado en el código, se generará una alarma de compilación:

```
[[nodiscard]] int funcion();
void metodo() {
    funcion(); // WARNING: valor de retorno de una funcion nodiscard es descartado.
}

[[nodiscard]] struct S { ... };
S crear_S();

void funcion() {
    crear_S(); // WARNING: valor de retorno de un type nodiscard es descartado.
}
```

El atributo `[[unused]]` marca una entidad que por algún motivo no se usa. Si el compilador fuese a marcar dicha entidad con una alarma, no lo hará si el atributo es usado:

```
// Una de las dos funciones no se usa dependiendo de UNA_CONDICION
static void funcion1() { ... }
static void funcion2() { ... } // warning: funcion2 no se usa

void iface() {
#ifdef UNA_CONDICION
    funcion1();
#else
    funcion2();
#endif
}
```

Este atributo no evita que el compilador compile la entidad marcada, así que ambas funciones serán compiladas pero ninguna será marcada con una alarma.

```
[[unused]] static void funcion1() { ... }
[[unused]] static void funcion2() { ... }
```

#### Atributos en espacios de nombres y enumerados

Documento técnico [`n4266`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4266.html).

A partir de C++17 se permite marcar espacios de nombres y enumerados con atributos.

### Sintaxis

#### Variables `inline`.

Documento técnico [`n4424`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4424.pdf).

C++ requiere que las funciones y variables `extern` tengan exáctamente una definición en el programa, este requerimiento se relajó para las funciones mediante el calificador `inline`. Las funciones inline se pueden definir en varios puntos pero todas sus definiciones deben ser la misma; lo mismo sucede para las funciones y variables instanciadas desde plantillas. Antes de C++17 no existía nada parecido para variables no plantilla pesea a que no es extraño necesitar un objeto global y único sin que este tenga que estar definido en una única unidad de traducción.

#### Definición de espacios de nombres anidados

Documento técnico [`n4230`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4230.html).

A partir de C++17 este código:

```
namespace A::B::C // Error en estandares previos a C++17
{
// codigo
}
```

Será equivalente a:

```
namespace A
{
namespace B
{
namespace C
{
// codigo
}
}
}
```

#### Extender `static_assert`.

Documento técnico [`n3928`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3928.pdf).

A partir de C++17 el segundo parámetro de `static_assert` es opcional:

```
static_assert ( true  != true ); // Correcto en C++17, incorrecto en estandares anteriores
static_assert ( false != false , "Falso debe ser falso" );
```

### Retorno múltiple y control de flujo más claros.

#### Enlazados estructurados<sup>1</sup>

Documento técnico [`p0217r2`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0217r2.html).

C++17 ofrece la posibilidad de declarar múltiples variables inicializadas desde una tupla o estructura:

```
std::tuple<T1,T2,T3> crear_tupla(/*...*/) { /*...*/ return { a, b, c }; }
auto [ x, y, z ] = crear_tupla(); // x deduce tipo T1, y deduce tipo T2, z deduce tipo T3

// iterador deduce tipo typeof(mapa)::iterator, insertado deduce bool
const auto [iterador, insertado] = mapa.insert({"clave", valor});

struct S { int x; volatile double y; };
S f();
// x deduce const int, y deduce const volatile double
const auto [ x, y ] = f();
```

#### Inicializador en instrucción `if`.

Documento técnico [`p0305r0`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0305r0.html).

C++ permite declarar e inicializar una variable en la instrucción `if`, si dicha variable es evaluable como condición booleana, se entrará en la rama verdadera de la instrucción; pero esto no es posible cuando la variable no es evaluable como booleana:

```
if (int no_multiplo_de_3 = x % 3)
{
std::cout << no_multiplo_de_3 << " no es multiplo de 3\n";
}

// Error! decltype(mapa)::iterator no es evaluable como condicion
if (auto iterador = mapa.find("clave"))
{ ... }
```

C++17 permite separar la declaración de la variable y su evaluación en la instrucción `if`:

```
if (auto iterador = mapa.find("clave"); iterador != mapa.end())
{
    std::cout << "clave existe en el mapa\n";
}

// Combinado con enlazados estructurados
if (const auto [iterador, insertado] = mapa.insert({clave, valor}); insertado)
{
    std::cout << clave << " ha sido insertada en el mapa\n";
}
```

#### Generalización del bucle `for` de rango.

Documento técnico [`p0184r0`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0184r0.html).

Permite que el tipo del iterador `begin` sea diferente al tipo del iterador `end`.

## Miscelánea

#### Literales hexadecimales de números en coma flotante

Documento técnico [`p0245r1`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0245r1.html).

Existe una notación científica en base-2 para valores numéricos en coma flotante en base hexadecimal: 0x3.ABCp-10. La mantisa se expresa en hexadecimal y el exponente en decimal interpretado con respecto a base 2. El menor valor de precisión simple expresable estándar [IEEE-754](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institute_of_Electrical_and_Electronics_Engineers) sería `0x1.0p-126`.

#### Asignación dinámica de memoria para datos alineados.

Documento técnico [`p0035r1`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0035r1.html).

C++11 añadió la posibilidad de especificar el alineamiento para objetos, peró no especificó ningún mecanismo para asignar memoria dinámica correctamente a estos objetos alineados, en C++17 se añaden sobrecargas a los operadores `new` y `delete` para especificar la alineación:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t size, std::align_val_t alignment);
void operator delete[](void* ptr, std::align_val_t alignment) noexcept;
void operator delete[](void* ptr, std::align_val_t alignment, std::size_t size) noexcept;
```

#### Elisión de copia **garantizada**.

Documento técnico [`p0135r0`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html).

En C++17 se garantiza que ciertas copias serán elididas, en particular: cuando el objeto a elidir es un valor temporal.

#### Refinamiento del orden de evaluación de expresiones para C++ idiomático.

Documento técnico [`p0145r2`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r2.pdf).

#### Garantías de progreso para la especificación técnica de Paralelismo V2.

Documento técnico [`p0299r0`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0299r0.html).

#### Literales de caracteres UTF8.

Documento técnico [`n4267`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4267.html).

C++11 añadió los literales de cadenas de texto UTF:

```
auto utf8     = u8"UTF8"; // Literal de cadena de texto codificado en UTF8
auto utf16    = u"UTF16"; // Literal de cadena de texto codificado en UTF16
auto utf32    = U"UTF32"; // Literal de cadena de texto codificado en UTF32
```

C++17 añade los literales de caracter de texto UTF:

```
auto utf8     = u8'8'; // Literal de caracter codificado en UTF8
auto utf16    = u'F';  // Literal de caracter codificado en UTF16
auto utf32    = U'X';  // Literal de caracter codificado en UTF32
```

#### Especificación de excepciones como parte del tipo de la función.

Documento técnico [`p0012r1`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0012r1.html).

La especificación de excepciones no forma parte del tipo de la función en estándares previos a C++17:

```
void f_throw() throw(int) {}
void f_no_throw() {}

using void_throw = void() throw(int);
// Presuntamente un puntero a funcion void que puede lanzar excepciones
void_throw *p;

p = f_throw;    // Correcto
p = f_no_throw; // Correcto tambien!
```

A partir de C++17 se generaría un error:

```
p = f_throw;    // Correcto
p = f_no_throw; // ERROR: No se puede convertir void() a void() throw(int)
```

#### Verificación estática de cabeceras.

Documento técnico [`p0061r1`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0061r1.html).

La instrucción `__has_include` permitirá comprobar si una cabecera está disponible

```
#if __has_include(<optional>)
#  include <optional>
#  define EXISTE_OPTIONAL 1
#elif __has_include(<experimental/optional>)
#  include <experimental/optional>
#  define EXISTE_OPTIONAL 1
#  define EXPERIMENTAL_OPTIONAL 1
#else
#  define EXISTE_OPTIONAL 0
#endif
```

#### Correcciones sobre conversiones de arreglos a punteros.

Documento técnico [`n4261`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4261.html).

#### Correcciones sobre constructores heredados.

Documento técnico [`p0136r1`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0136r1.html).

## Novedades de STL

### Tipos de datos

#### `std::variant` Union de tipado seguro.

Documento técnico [`p0088r2`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0088r2.html).

#### `std::optional` Objeto que puede contener un valor arbitrario, o tal vez no.

Documento técnico [`n4480`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4480.html#optional).

#### `std::any` Objeto que puede contener diferentes tipos.

Documento técnico [`n4480`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4480.html#any).

#### `std::string_view` Referencia a cadenas de texto.

Documento técnico [`n4480`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4480.html#string.view).

#### `std::shared_mutex` mutex compartido.

Documento técnico [`n4480`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4508.html).

### Invoke

#### `std::invoke` Objeto de llamada genérica.

Documento técnico [`n4169`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4169.html).

Puede llamar cualquier objeto llamable: puntero a función, función, función miembro... con una sintaxis unificada.

#### `std::apply` Llama una función con una tupla con parámetros.

Documento técnico [`n4480`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4480.html#tuple.apply).

### Especificación técnica de Sistema de Archivos v1

Documento técnico [`p0218r0`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0218r0.html).

- [`[class.path]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0218r0.html#class-path)
- [`[class.filesystem.error]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0218r0.html#Class-filesystem_error)
- [`[class.file_status]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0218r0.html#file_status)
- [`[class.directory_entry]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0218r0.html#Class-directory_entry)
- [`[class.directory_iterator]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0218r0.html#Class-directory_iterator) y [`[class.recursive_directory_iterator]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0218r0.html#class.rec.dir.itr)
- [`[fs.ops.funcs]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0218r0.html#Operational-functions)

### Especificación técnica de Paralelismo v1

Documento técnico [`n4071`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4071.htm).

### Especificación técnica de Fundamentos de Librería v1

Documento técnico [`p0220r1`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0220r1.html).

- [`[func.searchers]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4480.html#func.searchers) y [`[alg.search]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4480.html#alg.search).
- [`[pmr]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4480.html#memory.type.erased.allocator).
- [`std::sample`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4480.html#alg.random.sample).

Comment: ya llevo 3 intentos de terminar de leer y aun no puedo...