# C++23 ¿Qué está por llegar al lenguaje C++?

Tags: c++

Desde [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) el comité de estándares de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) se puso como meta aprobar un nuevo estándar cada 3 años. Así ha sido hasta la fecha y hemos tenido los siguientes estándares:

- [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) aprobado en Agosto de 2014.
- [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) aprobado en Marzo de 2017.

  - [¿Cuáles son las nuevas características de C++17?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/15499/2742).
  - [C++17 ¿Qué es? ¿No es C++?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108503/2742)<sup>1</sup>.
- [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) aprobado en Agosto 2020.

La estandarización se divide en cuatro grupos de trabajo:

- **Núcleo** (Core): Mantenimiento del lenguaje y estandarización de nuevas propuestas.
- **Evolución**: Desarrollo de nuevas características para el lenguaje.
- **Librería**: Mantenimiento de la librería estándar y estandarización de nuevas propuestas.
- **Evolución de librería**: Desarrollo de nuevas características para la librería estándar.

Estos son los documentos técnicos del nuevo estándar que me han parecido más interesantes:

| Documento técnico | Título | Grupo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [P0009R18](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p0009r18.html) | `mdspan` (Multi Dimensional Span) Extensión Multidimensional | Evolución de librería |
| [P1684R3](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1684r3.html) | `mdarray`: un array multidimensional análogo a `mdspan` | Evolución de librería |
| [P1255R8](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1255r8.pdf) | Una vista de 0 o 1 elementos: `views::maybe` | Evolución de librería |
| [P1899R3](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1899r3.html) | `stride_view` (vista a zancadas) | Evolución de librería |
| [P1967R8](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1967r8.html) | `#embed` un simple método de adquisición de recursos basado en preprocesador | Evolución |
| [P2165R4](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2165r4.pdf) | Compatibilidad entre `tuple`, `pair` y objetos parecidos a tuplas | Evolución de librería |
| [P2248R5](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2248r5.html) | Permitir inicializar algoritmos mediante listas | Evolución de librería |
| [P0288R7](https://wg21.link/P0288R7) | `move_only_function` (antes conocida como `any_invocable`) | Librería |
| [P0447R16](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0447r16.html) | Añadir `std::hive` (colmena) a la librería estándar | Librería |
| [P0627R5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0627r5.pdf) | Marcar código inalcanzable | Librería |
| [P0849R8](https://wg21.link/P0849R8) | `auto(x)` | Núcleo |
| [P2128R6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2128r6.pdf) | Operador de indizado multidimensional | Núcleo |
| [P1169R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1169r2.html) | Operador paréntesis estático `static operator()` | Evolución |
| [P2036R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2036r3.html) | Cambiar el ámbito del tipo del retorno arrastrado de las lambdas | Núcleo |
| [P1072R10](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1072r10.html) | `basic_string::resize_and_overwrite` | Librería |
| [P2012R1](https://wg21.link/P2012R1) | Arreglar el bucle `for` de rango | Evolución, Núcleo |
| [P2093R9](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2093r9.html) | Salida con formato | Evolución de librería |
| [P2276R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2276r1.pdf) | Arreglar `cbegin` | Librería, Evolución de librería |
| [P2322R4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2322r4.html) | `ranges::fold` | Evolución de librería |
| [P1240R2](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2022/p1240r2.pdf) | Reflexión escalable | Evolución |

Los nombres de los documentos técnicos tienen el siguiente significado:

- *PXXXX*: *P* de *paper* que en este contexto significa "*documento técnico*", el número a continuación de *P* es el identificador del documento.
- *RYY*: *R* de *revision* que en este contexto significa "*revisión*", el número a continuación de *R* es la cantidad de revisiones del documento, entendiendo revisiones como versiones del documento, en cada nueva versión se corrigen problemas, añaden, modifican o eliminan detalles, etc...

---

<sup>1</sup>Debido a algún extraño despiste, escribí dos hilos respecto C++17.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### `mdspan` (Multi Dimensional SPAN) Extensión Multidimensional.

Se propone diseñar un objeto vista (y otros objetos auxiliares) para tratar una colección de datos como si estuvieran organizados de manera multidimensional, también propone crear funciones que “recorten” porciones de una de estas extensiones.

El objeto `mdspan` puede ser usado mediante un mapeador (mapea un índice multidimensional en un elemento de la colección de datos) y un acesor (indica cómo se leen o escriben los elementos).

Las alternativas actuales a `mdspan` son:

- Formaciones nativas en que todas las dimensiones son conocidas en tiempo de compilación (por ejemplo: `int[3][4][5]`).
- Punteros-a-punteros(-a-punteros…), como `int ****`.
- Contenedores-de-contenedores(-de-contenedores…), como `vector<vector<array<int, N>>>`.
- [`std::gslice`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/gslice) que sólo funciona con [`std::valarray`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray).

Las cuales no se consideran óptimas ni suficientemente flexibles.

### `mdarray`: un array multidimensional análogo a `mdspan`.

Mientras que la propuesta anterior propone una vista (las vistas no son propietarias de los datos) a una abstracción de un array multidimensional, esta propuesta es sobre diseñar un array multidimensional (que sea propietario de los datos) que pueda interoperar con `mdspan`.

Dado que los datos pertenecerán al propio objeto, harán posibles casos de uso comunes como devolver un `mdarray` desde una función.

### Una vista de 0 o 1 elementos: `views::maybe`.

Este documento técnico propone la creación de una vista que puede contener un valor o puede no contenerlo, para casos de uso como el siguiente:

```
std::vector<std::optional<int>> v
{
    std::optional<int>{42},
    std::optional<int>{},
    std::optional<int>{6 * 9}
};

auto r = views::join(views::transform(v, views::maybe));

for (auto i : r) {
    std::cout << i; // Muestra 42 y 54
}
```

### `stride_view` (vista a zancadas).

No es posible recorrer un subconjunto de valores de un rango de manera espaciada, esto se debe en parte a la complejidad requerida por un iterador que pueda comportarse de esa manera. También significa que los ejemplos de a continuación no pueden convertirse de bucle a algoritmo:

```
int v[200] {};

for (auto i = 0; i < 200; i += 2) {
    v[i] = 42; // rellenar los pares
}

for (auto i = 0; i < 200; i += 3) {
    v[i] = f(); // transformar cada tres
}

for (auto i = 0; i < 200; i += 3) {
    for (auto j = i; j < 200; i += 3) {
        if (v[j] < v[i]) {
          stdr::swap(v[i], v[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Este documento propone incorporar a la librería algo parecido al adaptador de rangos `strided` de Boost.Range 2.0 que permitiría transformar el código anterior a algoritmos:

```
stdr::fill(v | stdv::stride(2), 42); // rellenar los pares
auto strided_v = v | stdv::stride(3);
stdr::transform(strided_v, stdr::begin(strided_v) f); // transformar cada tres

stdr::stable_sort(strided_v);
```

### `#embed` un simple método de adquisición de recursos basado en preprocesador.

Se necesita una nueva característica del lenguaje para poder incorporar datos directamente en el binario del programa, ya que las soluciones actuales son ineficientes. Crear una (larguísima) lista de números entre llaves es difícil de mantener y supone una gran carga para el procesador léxico.

Este documento propone crear una directiva de preprocesador que imite la directiva `#include`:

```
// Por defecto se considera 'unsigned char'...
const unsigned char icon_display_data[] = {
    #embed "art.png"
};

// ... pero cualquier tipo que pueda ser inicializado
// desde una constante entera es suficiente
const char reset_blob[] = {
    #embed "data.bin"
};
```

### Compatibilidad entre `tuple`, `pair` y objetos parecidos a tuplas.

`pair` es una especialicación de una tupla de dos elementos. `pair` y `tuple` comparten la mayoría de su interfaz. Notablemente una `tuple` puede construirse y ser asignada desde un `pair`, pero no es cierto en sentido contrario.

El objetivo de este documento se puede ilustrar en los ejemplos a continuación:

```
constexpr std::pair p{1, 3.0}; // se deduce pair<int, double>
constexpr std::tuple t{p};     // se deduce tuple<int, double>

std::pair<int, double> pp{t};  /* Ok, antes era necesario hacer:
std::pair<int, double> pp(get<0>(t), get<1>(t)); */

std::tuple<int,int> t = std::array{1, 2}; // Ok
std::tuple<int> t = std::array {1, 2};    // Error: El tamaño difiere

/* Esto ahora provocaría error pues ambos tipos son interconvertibles
haciendo que la expresión sea ambigua. */
auto x = true ? tuple{0,0} : pair{0,0};
```

### Permitir inicializar algoritmos mediante listas.

La inicialización por lista se introdujo en [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), su efectoes que una lista de inicialización puede usarse como argumento de función:

```
void f(std::complex<double>);
f({1.23, 4.56}); // Ok
```

Esto falla cuando se usan funciones plantillas ya que no puede deducirse un tipo a partir de una lista.

```
template <typename T> void g(T);
g({1, 2});     // Error: no se puede deducir T
```

Sin embargo es posible deducir el tipo en caso de que la plantilla disponga de un parámetro por defecto:

```
template <typename T = std::complex<double>> void h(T);
h({1.0, 2.0}); // Ok, se deduce std::complex<double>>
```

Se propone añadir parámetros por defecto a algunas funciones plantilla de la librería estándar de plantillas permitiendo así que sean llamadas mediante inicialización por lista, por ejemplo:

```
std::vector<std::complex<double>> n;
n.push_back({1.0, 2.0});

// Error, correcto si se aprueba esta propuesta.
std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), {1.0, 2.0});
```

### `move_only_function` (antes conocida como `any_invocable`).

Se propone una versión de `std::function` que:

1. No sea copialbe (sólo movible).
2. Resuelva el *bug* de la correctitud constante de `std::function` detallado en [n4348](https://api.csswg.org/bikeshed/www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4348.html).
3. De soporte a los cualificadores de función `const`, `volatile`, referencia y `noexcept`.
4. Carezca de `target_type` y `target`.
5. Su invocación tenga estrictas precondiciones.

### Añadir `std::hive` (colmena) a la librería estándar.

El objetivo de un contenedor en la librería estándar no puede ser proveer de la solución óptima en todos los escenarios. Existirán campos en que la solución óptima sea un contenedor propio que se ajuste a un escenario concreto. Aún así existen soluciones para casos generalizados que aún no forman parte de la librería estándar.

Una colmena (*hive*) es la formalización, extensión y optimización de lo que típicamente se conoce como *'bucket array'* cuyo concepto es:

> *Se dispone de múltiples bloques de memoria y una bandera para cada elemento que denota si el elemento está activo o borrado. Si un elemento está borrado es ignorado durante las iteraciones, cuando todos los elementos de un bloque están marcados como borrados dicho bloque se elimina. Si se inserta un nuevo elemento cuando todos los bloques están llenos, se crea un nuevo bloque de memoria.*

### Marcar código inalcanzable.

Los compiladores no pueden conocer todas las situaciones en que un código puede ejecutarse, siempre existirán programas en que el compilador no pueda determinar que una situación es imposible, por ejemplo:

```
void f(int numero_que_solo_es_0_1_2_o_3)
{
    switch (numero_que_solo_es_0_1_2_o_3)
    {
    case 0:
    case 2:
        f02();
        break;
    case 1:
        f1();
        break;
    case 3:
        f3();
        break;
    }
}
```

Ese código puede producir el siguiente código máquina...

```
cmp eax, 4
jae skip_switch
lea rcx, [jump_table]
jmp qword [rcx + rax*8]
```

... del que las dos primeras instrucciones son innecesarias. Este tipo de problemas surgen cuando el programador sabe que una situación es imposible pero no es obvio para el compilador; sería útil poder decirle al compilador que evite comprobaciones en tiempo de ejecución para casos que sabemos que son imposibles. Se propone para ello crear una función en la librería estándar:

```
namespace std {
    …
    [[noreturn]] void unreachable();
    …
}
```

Dejando el ejemplo inicial así:

```
void f(int numero_que_solo_es_0_1_2_o_3)
{
    switch (numero_que_solo_es_0_1_2_o_3)
    {
    case 0:
    case 2:
        f02();
        break;
    case 1:
        f1();
        break;
    case 3:
        f3();
        break;
    default:
        std::unreachable();
    }
}
```

### `auto(x)`.

Se propone `auto(x)` y `auto{x}` para convertir `x` en un *prvalue* (valor del lado derecho puro) como si se hubiera pasado `x` como argumento a una función por valor. Uno de los casos de uso se ilustra pasando el siguiente código:

```
void pop_front_alike(Container auto& x) {
    auto a = x.front();
    std::erase(x.begin(), x.end(), a);
}
```

A este código:

```
void pop_front_alike(Container auto& x) {
    std::erase(x.begin(), x.end(), auto(x.front()));
}
```

En el segundo caso queda explicitado que se quiere pasar una copia anónima. Sería una estandarización en el lenguaje de algo que a día de hoy es engorroso de usar:

```
template<class T>
constexpr decay_t<T> decay_copy(T&& v) noexcept(
    is_nothrow_convertible_v<T, decay_t<T>>) {
    return std::forward<T>(v);
}
```

### Operador de indizado multidimensional.

Se propone que el operador de indizado (`operator []`) pueda aceptar entre cero o múltiples argumentos (incluidos argumentos variádicos). No se propone cambiar el funcionamiento de las formaciones:

```
struct S {
    S operator[](auto ...);
} s;
s[1, 2, 3] = 7; // Correcto, llama a s.operator[](1, 2, 3)

int a[10];
a[1, 2, 3] = 7; // Error, no se permiten expresiones con coma en el indizado de formaciones
```

### Operador paréntesis estático `static operator()`.

Se propone permitir que el operador de llamada (también conocido como operador paréntesis `operator()`) sea estático en lugar de requerir que sea una función miembro no estática. Esto permitirá evitar el problema de pasar un `this` implícito cuando se usan objetos función sin miembros (como `std::less`).

### Cambiar el ámbito del tipo del retorno arrastrado de las lambdas.

La manera en que funciona la búsqueda de símbolos en las lambdas es sorprendente: funciona de manera diferente en el cuerpo de la lambda y en el tipo del retorno arrastrado. Por ejemplo este código no compila:

```
auto lambda = [j = 0]() mutable -> decltype(j) {
    return j++;
};
```

Esto sucede porque la variable `j` que se declara en la captura no es visible en el momento de preguntar por su tipo: la `j` de la captura forma parte del cuerpo de la lambda mientras que la `j` del tipo de retorno arrastrado se busca fuera, provocando el error de compilación, pero podría ser peor:

```
double j = 42.0;
// ...
// Varios centenares de líneas de código
// ...
auto lambda = [j = 0]() mutable -> decltype(j) {
    return j++;
};
```

El código anterior sí que compila pero hace que el retorno de la lambda sea `double` cuando probablemente la intención era que fuese `int`. Para evitar estos problemas se propone que la búsqueda de símbolos empiece la búsqueda en el retorno arrastrado de la lambda en lugar de buscar directamente en el ámbito externo a la lambda.

### `basic_string::resize_and_overwrite`.

La clase `basic_string` tiene ciertos problemas de rendimiento al inicializar o manipular; para esas tareas se debe tomar una difícil decisión:

- Inicializar espacio de más: `resize` inicializa a cero los datos y después los copia.
- Hacer copias de más: Rellenar un búfer temporal que será copiado a la cadena.
- Reservar por si acaso: `reserve` seguido de `append`, en cada operación de anexado se verifica la capacidad y de `basic_string`.

Para solucionar este problema se propone una nueva función miembro para la clase `basic_string`:

```
template<class Operation>
constexpr void resize_and_overwrite(size_type n, Operation op);
```

Cuyo comportamiento sería:

- Si `n <= size()`, borra los últimos `size() - n elements`.
- Si `n > size()`, anexa `n - size()` elementos inicializados por defecto.
- Llama `erase(begin() + op(data(), n), end())`.

### Arreglar el bucle `for` de rango.

En C++ es posible crear referencias colgantes (*dangling references*) por descuido:

```
// Funciones que devuelven temporales creados al vuelo
std::tuple<std::string, int, int> dame_tupla() { return {}; }
std::vector<std::string> dame_textos() { return {}; }

int main()
{
    // Referencias colgantes
    const auto &str1 = std::get<0>(dame_tupla());   // Referencia a sub-elemento de temporal.
    const std::string &str2 = dame_textos()[0];     // Referencia a sub-elemento de temporal.

    std::cout << str1 << ' ' << str2 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Al menos estas referencias colgantes son visibles en el código, pero si formasen parte de un bucle `for` de rango, quedarían ocultas:

```
for (auto elemento : get<0>(dame_tupla()))
    ...

for (auto elemento : dame_textos()[0])
    ...
```

Se propone modificar la implementación interna del bucle `for` de rango para esquivar este problema, pasando de su implementación actual:

```
{
    init-statement
    auto && __range = range-expression ;
    auto __begin = begin_expr ;
    auto __end = end_expr ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
        range-declaration = *__begin;
        loop-statement
    }
}
```

A esta:

```
{
    init-statementopt
    auto && range = for-range-initializer;
    [&](auto&& range) {
        auto begin = begin-expr ;
        auto end = end-expr ;
        for ( ; begin != end ; ++begin ) {
            for-range-declaration = * begin ;
            statement // return o goto o instrucciones co- afectan a todo el bucle
        }
    }( for-range-initializer );
}
```

### Salida con formato.

La función `std::format` de C++20 tiene problemas de rendimiento:

```
std::cout << std::format("Hola, {}!", nombre);
```

El código anterior crea una cadena temporal que requiere de su constructor y destructor para después pasar dicha cadena al operador de escritura con formato de `std::cout` cuando dicha cadena ya había sido formateada. Se propone crear una función que de formato al texto directamente en la salida:

```
std::print("Hola, {}!", nombre);
```

### Arreglar `cbegin`.

Las funciones `cbegin()` y `cend()` permiten acceder a una colección de datos con iteradores constantes, esto permite evitar que se puedan modificar los elementos iterados. Antes de C++20 este comportamiento estaba garantizado ya que las colecciones de datos propagaban la propiedad de sólo lectura a sus elementos (si la colección es de sólo lectura, también lo serán sus elementos). Pero desde C++20 se han proveído contenedores/rangos que no propagan la propiedad de sólo lectura.

Para tipos como `std::span` o vistas, se pueden modificar los elementos incluso aunque el contenedor/rango se declare como constante. Para esos tipos el código genérico `std::cbegin()`, `std::cend()` y similares está roto: siempre llama a los miembros `begin()` y `end()` (aunque los miembros `cbegin()` y `cend()` existan) por lo que es posible modificar elementos aún iterando con `cbegin()` y `cend()`.

Idealmente esto se debería solucionar, sin embargo otras propuestas opinan lo contrario: [P2276R0](http://wg21.link/P2276R0) y [P2278R0](http://wg21.link/P2278R0), por ello se proponen ciertos cambios para minimizar las consecuencias de este comportamiento:

- Proveer los miembros `cbegin()` y `cend()` para `std::span`.
- Proveer un mecanismo (conceptos) para verificar si un contenedor propaga o no la propiedad de sólo lectura.
- Deshabilitar `std::cbegin()`, `std::cend()`, etc... cuando una colección de datos no propague la propiedad de sólo lectura.
- Deshabilitar `std::ranges::cbegin()`, `std::ranges::cend()`, etc... cuando el rango no propague la propiedad de sólo lectura.

### `ranges::fold`.

Se propone crear un algoritmo [*fold*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) en la cabecera `<algorithm>` ya que la librería estándar carece del dicho algoritmo sobre rangos. Aunque existe una versión de *fold* basada en iteradores, actualmente recibe el nombre de `std::accumulate`, por defecto suma elementos y se aloja en la cabecera `<numeric>`. Pero *fold* es mucho más que sumar, así que es importante darle un nombre más genérico y evitar que la operación por defecto.

### Reflexión escalable.

Se propone dotar al lenguaje de mecanismos de reflexión estática, la propuesta incluye la creación de un nuevo operador unario (`^`):

```
constexpr std::meta::info refl = ^nombre_o_expresion;
```

Dando como resultado un valor conocido en tiempo de compilación que identifica el elemento de manera dependiente de implementación. El operador de reflexión se puede usar sobre:

- Un nombre de tipo.
- Un nombre de plantilla.
- Un espacio de nombres.
- El espacio de nombres raíz `::`.
- Una expresión.

Se propone que el tipo `std::meta::info` sea un nuevo tipo de escalar que sólo soporte conversión a `bool` y equidad/inequidad. Se usará como parámetro para diferentes funciones de reflexión como por ejemplo:

```
consteval bool is_namespace(info entity) {...};
consteval bool is_template(info entity) {...};
consteval bool is_type(info entity) {...};
```

Pero se puede usar también directamente:

```
typedef int I1;
typedef int I2;
static_assert(^I1 == ^I2);  // Correcto
static_assert(^I1 == ^int); // Correcto
```